# Creating Destination Folders in Directory with Subfolders /R

Tags: r, loops, directory

I am trying to create destination folders for camera data from 100 different auto-triggering remote cameras. The cameras will be checked 4 times so I want four subfolders within each camera folder. I created a loop to generate the camera folders which was successful but am at a loss using the dir.create function to create the subfolders in a separate loop especially since the file path needs to change within the loop. I tried to create a list of each new file path (Cam_Folders) and use that in the second loop. Please Help.

```
    ## Create Folders
    for (j in 1: length(Cam_Done_Names)){
      folder <-dir.create(paste0("/Users/dheit/Documents/RECaP/Cam_File_Test/",
         Cam_Done_Names[j]))

    ## Extract File Paths
    Cam_Folders <- list.files(path = 
      "/Users/dheit/Documents/RECaP/Cam_File_Test/",
      full.names = T)

    ## Create Subfolders
    for (i in 1: length(Check_Num)){
      folder<-dir.create(paste0(Cam_Folders,Check_Num[i]))
    }
```

UPDATE: I was able to solve the problem with looping within the loop

```
    for (i in 1:100){
      setwd(file.path("/Users/dheit/Hair_File_Test",
      Cam_Done_Names[i],sep = "/"))
      for (j in 1:4)
        dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/",Check_Num[j]))
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you have a list of cameras and know that each camera needs four folders, why dont you just do ````for( c in cam_names ) for( i in 1:4 ) dir.create( file.path( base_dir, c, i ) )```` ?

Answer (score 3):

`dir.create()` has a `recursive = TRUE` argument that allows you to create directories and any necessary sub-directories in the same call.

```
for(i_camera in 1:100) {
  for(j_sub in 1:4) {
    dir.create(path = paste0("/Users/dheit/Documents/RECaP/Cam_File_Test/camera", i_camera, "/sub_dir", j_sub), recursive = TRUE)
  }
}
```